# how to set fixed width of morris bar chart and align x labels respectively?

Tags: jquery, html, css, morris.js

how to set fixed width of Morris bar chart and align x labels respectively?
I can set the width of bars using jQuery. But, how do i align x labels with respective bar?

my code:

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [{n:'option1',c:'52'},{n:'option2',c:'12'},{n:'option3',c:'69'},{n:'option4',c:'5'},{n:'option5',c:'46'},{n:'option6',c:'5'}],
  xkey: 'n',
  ykeys: 'c',
  xLabelMargin: 1,
  labels: ['Lists'],
  hideHover:['auto'],
  barWidth: 20
});

$("#chart rect").attr("width",66);
```

Comment: i've tried changing width of bars using jquery. but i can't think of doing something how to align x labels.

Comment: do you have some sort of example, code, anything?

Comment: Yes, i've. Edited my question